# Python Multiprocessing Pool.map() issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a code which performs a lot of independent tasks in a loop which I'd like to convert to multiprocessing to speed it up. I've managed to speed up another looping task elsewhere in the code in this manner, and this one appears to be very similar. However, it fails giving the error below:

```
    File "Z:\Blade Test KTP\BladeTestOptimisationSoftware\python\source\SteadyStateMP.py", line 2196, in <module>
    x0,FitnessTracker=GAMainFunc(GAPopulation,GAGeneration,Crossover,Mutation,FitnessScaling,SwapVariables,Bounds,Args+(False,))
    File "Z:\Blade Test KTP\BladeTestOptimisationSoftware\python\source\SteadyStateMP.py", line 1480, in GAMainFunc
    result = pool.map(func,PopulationList)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
    NameError: global name 'NodesList' is not defined
```

Unfortunately, a runable example isn't feasible because of the amount of code, the size of the input files and the fact that I'd get in trouble for putting it in the public domain... I've not managed to replicate the problem on a smaller scale either (as I mentioned above, I succesfully implemented multiprocessing elsewhere and I've made the code very similar). The structure of my code is shown below:

```
    from functools import partial
    import multiprocessing as mp

    def OptimFunc(x0,SectionProps,SectionToAnalyse,Nodes,ElNormTarget,OptimInput,
              K,Kl,M,Rlb,Damping,Cdb,TestType,TestStandPitch,BladePitch,gravity,FullReturn):
        #Do some stuff and return a scalar value. NodesList can be printed 

    def SwapVariables(Consts,string):
        x0=StringToArray(string)
        return OptimFunc(x0,*Consts[0])

    PopulationList=[list,containing,different,trial,solutions,for,optimisation,function]
    Consts=(SectionProps,SectionToAnalyse,Nodes,ElNormTarget,OptimInput,
                  K,Kl,M,Rlb,Damping,Cdb,TestType,TestStandPitch,BladePitch,gravity)

    func=partial(SwapVariables,[Consts])
    NoCPUs=mp.cpu_count()
    pool=mp.Pool(processes=NoCPUs) 
    result = pool.map(func,PopulationList)
    Error=np.array(result)
    pool.close()
```

A non-parallel implementation of this works fine (literally replacing pool.map() with itertools.map() or by looping). The only difference between this and my succesful implementation is that NodesList is a numpy array, so I tried putting the array inside a dictionary and a list (which are the types of variables the function used in my succesful parallel loop takes) with the same error. I avoid global variables like the plague so I am insulted that python would suggest I'm using them! The weirdest part is that I can print NodesList inside the OptimFunc before it is used in anger.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: From what I read I cannot discern whether NodesList gets passed to the function or if the function creates that object. Another thing I seem to remember from using mutltiprocessing was that sometimes I had to put the function in an importable module so that the different processes could properly access it.

Comment: It gets passed to it from the main function, and is a numpy array. Having to import it sounds weird, as I say I'm having no trouble with my other parallelised function.

Comment: where do you define `NodesList`? You should try define it inside OptimumFunc if possible and see if it works

Comment: Is it one same  array getting passed to every optimisation function?

Comment: Yep, I used the SwapVariables function to put the x0 array at the end of the variable list so that the constants can be passed first which works with functools.partial.

Comment: Can you provide an example that we can actually run to reproduce this?